# Postgres not installing in Bundler (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, bundler

I am getting pretty desperate, i have tried every answer on the subject but nothing seems to work.

the error log looks like this:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150523-16458-46bzoo.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
sh: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
sh: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config: No such file or directory
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kevinegstorf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/pg-0.18.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kevinegstorf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/pg-0.18.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Installing gem install pg -v '0.18.2' gives me back the same error
I hope someone can help me. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find your pg_config file and add it to the build command:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
```

Since your pg_config file is located at /usr/local/bin/pg_config Did you try the command(edited) above?

If that doesn't help maybe try:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Comment: tnx for your very fast reply. I am still pretty much a noob on the subject.when I do "which pg_config" i get this. so i just paste this "/usr/local/bin/pg_config" behind "bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config"

Comment: i get this after running it You are replacing the current global value of build.pg, which is currently "--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/usr/local/bin/pg_config" and when running bundle install i get the same error message

Comment: since `which` can  find it that means it's in the path so the problem may be something else.

Comment: I should have looked  more closely sorry. At this point it can't find the postgres client library. Are you sure you have it installed? How did you install postgres? With homebrew?

Comment: yes i used homebrew and i reinstalled rails out of total desperation later on

Comment: the issue is with your postgres installation. How did you install it? brew install postgresql?

Comment: Based on the path it looks like Postgres was installed with Postgres.app: http://postgresapp.com/

Comment: ah yes.. obviously. my mistake.

Comment: did you try sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg as mentioned in the edited answer?

Comment: isn't their a way to uninstall everything and reinstall it?

Comment: i have tried all the other posts on this matter and i still get this error

Comment: env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg worked!! tnx so much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you already install Postgres.app in Mac, 
you should copy `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Version/9.4/bin/pg_config` to another place. For example `/home/pg_config`

then run

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/home/pg_config
bundle install
```